# Office Script Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, power-automate, office-scripts

Continuing on my last question, I have converted my data from worksheets to tables, but I run into another problem.

I have two scripts, call them "convert" and "combine". If I run them separately, they work. Either I put them into the same script or run them together in a Power Automate flow, which is my expectation. I got an error at line 17 *“We were unable to run the script. Please try again.
Office JS error: Line 17: Range setValues: Le nombre de lignes ou de colonnes dans le tableau d’entrée ne correspond pas à la taille ou aux dimensions de la plage."*

Tried disable line 17" //targetRange.setValues(headerValues); " and then get an error at Line 31
*"We were unable to run the script. Please try again.
Office JS error: Line 31: Table addRows: Le nombre de lignes ou de colonnes dans le tableau d’entrée ne correspond pas à la taille ou aux dimensions de la plage."*

Where is the conflict?

convert

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        
    let worksheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
    for (let i = 1; i < worksheets.length; i++) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[i];
        selectedSheet.getRange("1:1").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
        let newTable = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("A1:AJ2"), true);
    }
    workbook.getWorksheet('Feuil1')?.delete();
}
```

combine

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Delete the "Combined" worksheet, if it's present.
     workbook.getWorksheet('Combined')?.delete(); 
     workbook.getWorksheet('Feuil1')?.delete();

  // Create a new worksheet named "Combined" for the combined table.
     const newSheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Combined');

  // Get the header values for the first table in the workbook.
  // This also saves the table list before we add the new, combined table.
    const tables = workbook.getTables();
    const headerValues = tables[1].getHeaderRowRange().getTexts();
    console.log(headerValues);
    
  // Copy the headers on a new worksheet to an equal-sized range.
 
    const targetRange = newSheet.getRange('A1').getResizedRange(headerValues.length-1, headerValues[0].length-1);

  //targetRange.setValues(headerValues); 

  // Add the data from each table in the workbook to the new table.
     const combinedTable = newSheet.addTable(targetRange.getAddress(), true);
     for (let table of tables) {
     let dataValues = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getTexts();
        let rowCount = table.getRowCount();

    // If the table is not empty, add its rows to the combined table.
     if (rowCount > 0) {
         combinedTable.addRows(0, dataValues);
    }      
  }  
}
```

Comment: Nicee you've added some more detail, I'll take a closer look at see. I had to do so much of this debugging when I did this last time haha

Comment: Unluckily I dont have access to powerautomate right now so no office scripts, but it should be fairly simple to solve if you just console log the values and ranges and check the sizes

Comment: Thank you, Max.  headerValues =16 arrays headerValues.length =1 headerValues[0].length= 36 I count A-AJ are 36 columns. Are these results helpful?

Comment: still trying, separate them into two flows, when run the second script, got "We were unable to run the script. Please try again.
Runtime error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
clientRequestId: 868d5243-8e75-4fc4-9b4a-0694aa216e5f"
werid it works manually in excel and it's an example

Comment: Yea not sure tbh.. from the values should be okay. For first error I would try see if you can get dimensions of resized range also for debug. Maybe +/1 on the resizing accordingly. For other issue I would also change the addRows(0,dataValues) to -1 index so it just does last

Comment: I personally never work with tables. Get your data as "Array of Objects" then ensure each object has the same keys, then paste to a range. Do you need tables? Even if you do, I'd do the above, then convert the final range to a table.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you're trying to set a range of values that does not fit the shape of the values. Array of values has too few or too many elements, something along those lines.

Not sure if the code you provided is including combine convert etc.. but either way if they work separately I would guess that the output of one is not compatible with the input of the other.

This is a guess since not sure which parts of the code represent what, but if that's the only code, it could be that your hardcoded selection range `"A1:AJ2"` is not taking into consideration the above range deletion.